# Can I replace Harddisks to change the OS

Tags: linux, windows

I have a Server machine which I want to use with two Operating Systems.

I cannot do the below things :
1. Use a virtual machine.
2. Install a dual boot

I already have windows installed on the server. I was wondering if I put a new HDD and install Linux on it. Later can I replace the Windows HDD and get my system to work as before ?

Actually I have to test my application on Windows/Linux for performance but want to avoid the dual boot option as I need to reserve a large part of HDD for the DB.

Is it possible to replace HDD and migrate to new OS on same machine ?

Comment: Why can't you virtualize? Swapping hard disks needlessly is silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can think of the hard drive as having the 'Personality' of the computer, when you swap in a new hard drive and boot from there, you are giving it a 'personality transplant' :)

If you have any other hard drives in there, say, with data on them, there are further considerations. If you have data that was saved with Windows, but you then swap boot drives and manipulate your data in Linux, make sure you understand the implications and have backups just in case things break.

However if you only have a boot drive, it is perfectly fine to swap a Windows boot disk and a Linux boot disk, if a little cumbersome.

If your PC is modern and uses secure boot/UEFI there are other things you may need to take in to account - maybe someone else can expand on that?